# can I default-assign a hash key and also += in a value on one line (in Ruby)?

Tags: ruby, hash, increment

I cannot do this

```
r = {a:nil}
Array.wrap(r[:a]) += [2,3]

#=> SyntaxError: (irb):126: syntax error, unexpected tOP_ASGN, expecting $end
```

Because the result of the wrap (or an `||=`) is not the original reference.

of course, it is fine to do it in two lines:

```
r = {a:nil}
r[:a] ||= []
r[:a] += [2,3]

=> {:a=>[2, 3]}
```

Can I do it in one?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, in part because I'm not familiar with `wrap`, which I believe is part of `ActiveSupport`.  However if you just want `r[:a] => [2,3]` if `r[:a] == nil` (after `r = {a: nil}`), isn't it just: `r[:a] ||= [2,3]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(r[:a]||=[]).concat [2,3]

r[:a]
# => [2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
(r[:a] ||= []).concat [2, 3]
```

To assign the hash too:

```
((r ||= {})[:a] ||= []).concat [2, 3]
```

One liners are not the best way to make readable and maintainable code, though.

Comment: I think it's a dupe answer, now.  FWIW